# Can we implement EarlGrey on Cucumberish?

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, bdd, earlgrey

I am new on Xcode.
we already implement EarlGrey framework as our native automation ios testing framework.
 Then we want to implement BDD test on our automation IOS.
I can run Cucumberish on UI testing, and run EarlGrey on Unit Test.
But I'm getting a problem when combining EarlGey and Cucumber.
It throws an error like this

[image]

as we know Cucumberish is based on Objective-C,
 I think that error happens when EarlGrey framework converting to Objective-c but I am not sure because I am still new on swift and Objective-c.

i put my project on my github : https://github.com/tnabror/CucumberishEarlGrey

Comment: You're reimplementing the EG macro. Can you change the class name?

Comment: @gran_profaci what changes on the class name?

Comment: Change EarlGrey to something else - EarlGreyCucumberish or so. See if that builds.

Comment: @gran_profaci the problem still appear when changing EarlGrey name

Comment: Firstly, EG will no longer be supported in Unit Tests going forward. Look at the UI Test based implementation of EG - 

https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/earlgrey2

Comment: @gran_profaci so, is that mean EarlGrey will support BDD test on EG2?